# Set Word Content Control from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have a word template that I use for documentation.  I would like to set the content controls in the word document from MS Access.  I figured out how to set the items in Word,

```
ActiveDocument.ContentControls(14).Checked = True
activedocument.ContentControls(1).DropdownListEntries.Item(3)enter code here
```

But when I try to do that from Access I cant figure out how to call the content controls.

This is the code I use when replacing bookmarks, ive tried to put content controls in with it, but no luck:

```
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
WordApp.Documents.Add Template:=strTemplateLocation, NewTemplate:=False

With WordApp.Selection

.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="COMPANY"
.TypeText [fac]
'that works

Dim oCtrl As ContentControl
set oCtrl = .ContentControl(14)
oCtrl.Checked = True
```

I then get a compile error stating "Method or data member not found".  With "ContentControl" on the second to last line highlighted.

Its been a long time since I worked with code, so please excuse me if something obvious is off.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around with it for a while and found the fix.

Added:

```
dim wDoc as Word.Document
```

Removed .Selection from the With statement

```
With WordApp
```

Added .Selection to the bookmark replacement statements

```
.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="COMPANY"
.Selection.TypeText [fac]
```

And then for the checkbox's:

```
ActiveDocument.ContentControls(6).Checked = True
```

Now working.